# Jquery how to change color of one word in select <option> box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have select-option box with word Select and language names

If language name is not selected, then see word Select.

If I see word Select, on page load want to see the word Select in red color.

However it is not red. If I click on the box and navigates to some language name, then word Select becomes red. But I need it red if box is not clicked (on page load to pay user attention).

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/z7264x9t/

And here is code

```
<select name="language" id="language">
<option id="red_color">Select</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="ru">Русский</option>
<option value="lv">Latviešu</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
var language_check = $("#language").val();
if ( language_check == 'Select' ) {
$('#red_color').css('color', 'red');
}
else if ( language_check != 'Select' ) {
$('#red_color').css('color', 'green');
}
```

I suppose it is because `red_color` is id of `<option>`, not the word Select. But how to define id for the word Select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/z7264x9t/6/

```
   check();
function check(){
    var language_check = $("#language").val();
if ( language_check == 'Select' ) {
    $("#language").css({'border-color': 'red','color':'red'});
    $('#language option:first-child').css({'color':'red'});
    $('#language>option+option').css({'color':'black'});
}
else if ( language_check != 'Select' ) {
    $("#language").css({'border-color': 'black','color':'green'});
//    $("#language option:first-child").css({'color':'black'});
    $("#language option[value="+language_check+"]").css({'color':'green'});
}
}

$("#language").change(function(){
check();
});
```

Updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/z7264x9t/6/

Comment: if you will select any other word, then it will be green.. if you will select 'select, then it will be red. still working on it.. give me a minute more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery `blur()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7264x9t/4/)

```
  $('#language').on('change',function(){
       $('#language').blur();
      $('#red_color').css('color', 'red');
    });
```

Reference : [jQuery blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$('#language option').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('value') == 'ru'){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
   }
});
```

should work